# Why does the "for" loop not work and program stops?

Tags: c

When I compile the program it seems to work normally but, when it asks for the "cuadrados", the program just stops:

```
int main(){

int *ptrs, suma=0, n, i, m;

printf("cuantos numeros al cuadrado quiere?: ");
scanf("%i", &n);

int numero[n], cubo[n];
*ptrs=numero
```

Here is when the program stops:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("escriba los cuadrados: "); 
scanf("%i", numero[i]);

}


printf("Cuantos numero al cubo quiere?: ");
scanf("%i", m);

 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("escriba los cubos: ");
scanf("%i", cubo[i]);
}
```

I had this issue before but I can't understand why it does not keep running; it just asks for 1 number and then stops with no error or warning.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it stops compiling'? Do you mean it stop executing and wait for an input ?do you provide an input ? What are your inputs ?

Comment: You must pass the *address* of the variable to `scanf()` like the first time. So `scanf("%i", m);` must be `scanf("%i", &m);` and similar for the arrays, I leave you to figure them out. Didn't the compiler tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("escriba los cuadrados: "); 
scanf("%i", &numero[i]);
}

printf("Cuantos numero al cubo quiere?: ");
scanf("%i", &m);

 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("escriba los cubos: ");
scanf("%i", &cubo[i]);
}
```

You need to give address of the variable in `scanf` using `&` operator

Answer (score 1):

This will crash because `scanf` needs a *pointer-to-int*, not an *int*:

```
scanf("%i", numero[i]);
```

This will not:

```
if (scanf("%i", &numero[i]) == 1) {
    /* do something */
}
else {
     /* scanf failed */
}
```

Note that not testing the `scanf` return value is always asking for trouble. As is not using your compiler's maximum warning level and turning all warnings into errors.